# Why doesn't python recognize netCDF even though netCDF is loaded in the environment

Tags: python, netcdf, netcdf4

I am working in a Linux envirnmont where Python,netCDF and CDO are already installed and and loaded in. I am failry new to all this and not sure why I get the following error when I try to import netCDF4 with python:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'netCDF4'`

I did not install any of those mudules they were already installed.

I want to open and plot netCDF files and I did the following

`Python 3.10.8 (main, Jun  2 2023, 20:45:07) [GCC 12.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > import netCDF4
> > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > > File "", line 1, in 
> > > ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'netCDF4'`

I have ckecked that python and netcdf are loaded so I do not understand what the issue is
`

Comment: How were these libs installed ? Are you using the same python interpreter ? Have you actually checked if they are installed ?

Comment: Through my uni have access to a  high performace computing facility in order to do my bachelor's thesis. They provide software such as netcdf, python etc. But I am having the aforementioned issue. I checked with the 'module list' command and with 'which ncdump', all of them show me that netCDF is loaded

Comment: The question is slightly confusing. You say "Python, netCDF and CDO are already installed". First, is CDO relevant here? Second, what you are saying is installed? netCDF system libraries or the netCDF4 Python package? If the only thing installed are the system libraries, then you will need to install netCDF4 using pip or conda

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.